# Error in Sharepoint list validation while trying to apply pnp templating

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

Getting the following error while trying to add list validation formula
"The formula refers to a column that does not exist.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column."

Added the column field for the list formula from UI and PNP templating got succeed 2 - 3 times but after few hours getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seem to be with PNP provision code itself. While provisioning the template to a new teams, the code checks if the list validation formula's field matches to the list field before the list fields are added. Hence, getting the error.
Hope issue is solved in new version of pnp template.

Workaround:
Add list & fields then do provision with list validation formula. It works.